# JavaScript display message using user's time in seconds

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, time

I have a list of 5000 text strings and I've assigned a time to each one (between 0–86400 seconds)

I want to get the user's current time and display the corresponding text string, and then update the text displayed when the user's time changes to match the next text string and so on...

I'm very new to JavaScript, so I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but I had the idea of using two arrays, one which stores the text strings and another which stores the times. The code could find the correct time from the 'time' array and then display the text string with the same index from the other array. If the user's current time falls between two values, the first value should be selected.

For example:

```
var interval = [0, 1728, 3456, 5184, 6912, 8640, 10368, 12096, 13824, 15552,
17280, 19008, 20736, 22464, 24192, 25920, 27648, 29376, 31104, 32832,
34560, 36288, 38016, 39744, 41472, 43200, 44928, 46656, 48384, 50112,
51840, 53568, 55296, 57024, 58752, 60480, 62208, 63936, 65664, 67392,
69120, 70848, 72576, 74304, 76032, 77760, 79488, 81216, 82944, 84672];

var textstring = ["Verse 1", "Verse 2", "Verse 3", "Verse 4", "Verse 5", "Verse 6", "Verse 7", "Verse 8", "Verse 9", "Verse 10",
"Verse 11", "Verse 12", "Verse 13", "Verse 14", "Verse 15", "Verse 16", "Verse 17", "Verse 18", "Verse 19", "Verse 20",
"Verse 21", "Verse 22", "Verse 23", "Verse 24", "Verse 25", "Verse 26", "Verse 27", "Verse 28", "Verse 29", "Verse 30",
"Verse 31", "Verse 32", "Verse 33", "Verse 34", "Verse 35", "Verse 36", "Verse 37", "Verse 38", "Verse 39", "Verse 40",
"Verse 41", "Verse 42", "Verse 43", "Verse 44", "Verse 45", "Verse 46", "Verse 47", "Verse 48", "Verse 49", "Verse 50"];

function displayverse() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    var currenttime = (hour * 3600) + (minute * 60) + second;

    for (var i = 0; i < interval.length; i++) {
        if (currenttime >= interval[i][0] && currenttime < interval[i][1]) {
            document.getElementById('verse').innerHTML = textstring[i][0];
        }
    }
}
```

My current code isn't working. I think the 'if' statement I've written is incorrect. Does anyone have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/wrgt1/9bs4eu5q/1/

Comment: if (currenttime >= interval[i][0] && currenttime < interval[i][1]) {  should be replaced with if (currenttime >= interval[i] && currenttime < interval[i]) {

Comment: And for textstring[i][0] replace it with textstring[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code: `interval[i]` is not an array, it's already a value, so you're getting `undefined` on `interval[i][0]` or `interval[i][1]`. To get value you're need just `interval[i]` for the first value and `interval[i+1]` for the second one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < interval.length; i++) {
    if (currenttime >= interval[i] && currenttime < interval[i+1]) {
        document.getElementById('verse').innerHTML = textstring[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified fiddle, there was a code error:

https://jsfiddle.net/ujfpy47a/

Modified code:

```
     for (var i = 0; i < interval.length; i++) {
        if (currenttime >= interval[i] && currenttime < interval[i+1]) {
          document.getElementById('verse').innerHTML = textstring[i];
        }
      }
```